# Bootstrap 4 set width:100%; to child of div item that has "container" class

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

i have used container class for the parent div

here:

```
<div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
              <div style="width:100%; height:300px;z-index:-1" class="col-lg-12 mt-n4 bg-white text- 
                 center">
               <div style="margin: 0;position: absolute;top: 50%;left: 50%;-ms-transform: 
                  translate(-50%, 
                 -50%);transform: translate(-50%, -50%);">
                 <img class="rounded-circle border border-info p-1" style="width:150px;height:150px;" 
                 src="~/ProfileImages/@currentuser.ImageProfile">
                <h4 class="text-center font-weight-bold text-info">@Model.ApplicationUser.ArName</h4>
               </div>
              </div>
         </main>
</div>
```

now: i want to make width for div inside the parent 100% but i could not with this code:

```
 <div style="width:100%; height:300px;z-index:-1" class="col-lg-12 mt-n4 bg-white text-center">
        <div style="margin: 0;position: absolute;top: 50%;left: 50%;-ms-transform: translate(-50%, 
        -50%);transform: translate(-50%, -50%);">
            <img class="rounded-circle border border-info p-1" style="width:150px;height:150px;" 
            src="~/ProfileImages/@currentuser.ImageProfile">
            <h4 class="text-center font-weight-bold text-info">@Model.ApplicationUser.ArName</h4>
        </div>
</div>
```

how can i remove bootstrap "container" class effects on child element?

Answer (score 1):

```html
//Try this One, It works fine and responsive in all widths and no need to write that much css

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body style="width: auto;height: auto;">

    <div class="container mt-2">
        <div class="card bg-white text- 
                 center" style="width:20rem">
            <img class="img-fluid card-img-top"
                src="https://cnet2.cbsistatic.com/img/-e95qclc6pwSnGE2YccC2oLDW_8=/1200x675/2020/04/16/7d6d8ed2-e10c-4f91-b2dd-74fae951c6d8/bazaart-edit-app.jpg">
            <div class="card-body">

                <h4 class="text-center font-weight-bold text-info">@Model.ApplicationUser.ArName</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```